# Count number of rows of a table and add it as Title in a chart in Qlik Sense

Tags: dashboard, qliksense

I am new to Qlik Sense, I have created a table chart and I want to set the name of the title as -
'Data with 700 rows'

My table name is say 'data'
what I have tried -

`RowNo(TOTAL)` and `NoOfRows()` both returns 1

eg - = 'Data with ' & RowNo(TOTAL) & ' rows'

it returns - 'Data with 1 rows'

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title, being part of the chart, is not "aware" of the content of the chart itself. And because of this functions like `RowNo()` and `NoOfRows()` will not return anything meaningful.

In the example below the table have 1 dimension/field - `Users`. The field have 7 values. To show 7 in the title the title expression should count these values:

`= 'Data with ' & count(Users) & ' rows'`

And the result will be:

[image: result table]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sir I have 34 columns, what should I do in that case?

Comment: if the table have an unique/low level values in one of the columns - customer id, client id, transaction id etc. it will be enough to count the values in this field in order to get the number of rows